# Are tagged classes in Java acceptable when simply conveying a value and (differing) associated attributes?

Tags: java, architecture, software-design

I have an object representing a network session, with a list of actions to execute - so it could send a message, receive a message, pause, receive a message and receive a message, for example. Actions have some extra data associated with them - for example, when receiving a message you have a regular expression that matches it, whereas when sending a message you just have the literal message and whether to retransmit.

I'd like the session object to handle the actual receiving or sending of messages - those rely on state contained in the session object (fields to fill in, what to do on failure, and so on) and I think it's cleaner to have the session do that based on the current action than to delegate it to the action and pass the action all of its state.

Instinctively I'd have a single Action class, with a field indicating its type (send/receive/pause) and some other fields, not all of which would be used for a given type (message to send/regexp to match/pause duration). But I've been reading Effective Java, which says that [using a "tagged class" like this is bad and is better done with inheritance](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/classes-and-interfaces/ch04lev1sec8). I'm not really sure how to make that work, though - if I had a RecvAction, SendAction and PauseAction subclass, I think my session object would have to do an instanceof check to figure out the right behaviour, and I was under the impression that instanceof checks are a bit of a code smell.

What is the right approach to this problem, in terms of good Java style? If I have a value object conveying a piece of primary information (send a message) and related secondary information (what message to send), is that a legitimate exception where I can use tagged classes, or is there a cleaner way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you need this kind of flexibility, you can toss the tags, and allow the actions to be just plain objects that can be caught by accompanied processors. E.g. a list of `Processor` classes with method `boolean supports(Action action)` and `void handle(Action action)`. You will also need an orchestrator, which would hold an arbitrary list of processors, and for the message received, the processors will be asked if they support it, and the one that answers `true` on `supports(Action action)`, will get `handle(Action action)` called respectively.

E.g.

```
public interface Processor<A extends Action> {
    boolean <T extends A> supports(T action);
    void handle(A action);
}

public ActionRouter {
    private List<Processor> processors = new LinkedList<Processor>();
    public void handle(Action a) {
        for (Processor p : processors) {
            if (p.supports(a)) {
                p.handle(a);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can achieve acceptable level of cohesion, e.g. by implementing focused action processors, like `SendActionProcessor implements Processor<SendAction>`.

Yeah, the `instanceof` doesn't seem very elegant, but can be tolerated for the purpose. If you don't like it and to not to repeat yourself, implement an abstract processor class, which will take the needed type as a constructor argument, and will encapsulate the acceptance by type.

On the other side, it's not always `instanceof` test. Your `handle` method would act as a predicate, and can test for the state of your actions before deciding to handle it. Really, depends on what you need.